# tools for VBA, on multi user Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, multi-user

We have multiple users on shared excel workbook.
When there is "John", I can see on witch cell is currently working.
Is there any way how VBA should also get it?

For example.

`ActiveCell.Value` -> returns value from cell where i'm active.

`?????.John.value` -> returns value where Jon is active

Thank you

Edit:

Useful information is active location which i can see but transfer it into VBA please
[image: example of location of active cell, another person]

Comment: Well, I don't think there is such default function in excel, only Google sheet can let you know who is working on each cell `live`.

Comment: You can get a list of active users see [Workbook.UserStatus property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.userstatus) but not in which cell they are working.

Comment: It is not such a standard option/function, but with a little imagination, I think you can build a working solution. Not to **see", but to return the last active cell of all working users. Consuming some Excel resources, but something like this: using `SheetSelectionChange` event to log each user selected cell in a text file, existing in the same folder with the shared workbook. When need to see the user and its active cell, instead of `...John.value` you can use a function `userActiveCell(strUser as String_) As String`, opening the log file and finding the last occurrence of the user sel cell.

Comment: The function can be called as `Debug.Print userActiveCell("John")`.

Comment: @FaneDuru I would use a hidden worksheet for that. Less overhead, and automatically comes with the workbook. Also you are able to use lookup functions.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It can be kept in a hidden worksheet, too, but I still think the overhead may be bigger in case of saving the data in the workbook. Without saving the workbook, the other users cannot see the records, I am afraid. And the logging procedure will firstly check the text file existence and immediately create it, if missing. No need of copying it with the workbook. Just checking its size and delete from time to time, to decrease the text processing part.

Comment: @FaneDuru huh I never used shared workbooks. But I thought if you can see the cell that another user is working at (*"I can see on witch cell is currently working."*), that the data would be changed live too. Otherwise seeing the cell does not make much sense if you cannot work on data live.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ He probably wants to preliminarily check if somebody else drops data in a specific cell and avoiding it. Just guessing... Only now I observed the part regarding "seeing on which cell is somebody else working". He maybe refers to a Google sheet. It is not possible to see anything in a shared workbook, except your screen. Or accessing it remotely :)

Comment: There's a difference between the old "shared workbook" and Office 365 "collaborative editing" - in the second you you see who is working where, and any data they enter shows up for you also...

Comment: @Tim Williams: Ups... I never used it on a shared workbook. Should I also understand that placing values in a hidden sheet, these values can be read by another user without needing to previously save the workbook?

Comment: @FaneDuru - I would guess so, but I've not done any testing on that...

Comment: So far nobody is pointing to correct direction. But thanks for trying.